# Espresso activity start failing with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I am try to write a simple test for the below scenario:

On my main activity I have a button (with id validationButton) and when users clicks on it starts a new activity (specific ValidationActivity). So I want to test that when user click the button validation activity is going to start. My code is this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.P])
    class MainActivityTest {
    
    @get:Rule
    val activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun intentsInit() {
        launch(MainActivity::class.java)
        Intents.init()
    }

    @After
    fun intentsTearDown() {
        Intents.release();
    }

    @Test
    fun click_start_validation_should_go_to_validation_screen() {
        val mockContext = mock(Context::class.java)
        //val scenario = launch(MainActivity::class.java)
        onView(withId(R.id.validationButton)).perform(click())
        assertThat(getIntents().first()).hasComponentClass(ValidationActivity::class.java)
    }
}
```

When i run it, test fails with these logs:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: androidx.test.internal.platform.util.TestOutputEmitter.addOutputProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)Z

```
at androidx.test.espresso.GraphHolder.baseLayer(GraphHolder.java:12)
at androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.<clinit>(Espresso.java:2)
at mobile.personaldemo.MainActivityTest.click_start_validation_should_go_to_validation_screen(MainActivityTest.kt:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:575)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:263)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to put `Thread.sleep(time: Milis)` after `onView(withId(R.id.validationButton)).perform(click())`?
Maybe the activity didn't load fully and espresso is trying to verify it, and that fails the test.

Alternatively, you can use some UI component from the activity that you're opening, such as TextView or anything, and assert that the UI component from the given activity is shown.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried `Thread.sleep(time: Milis)` and it works fine now. I also try using `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)` and then call on test class

 `onView(withId(R.id.validationButton)).perform(click())
 intended(hasComponent(ValidationActivity::class.java.name), times(2))`

It also worked. Thanks again!